# Can I include a library in a function residing in said library?

Tags: c, include

I am somewhat new to programming and I'm trying to make a project where I make my own function library. Inside of said library I have one function that uses two other functions in it too. Can I `#include` "library.h" on the function inside library.h to use the other two functions? Thanks in advance =)

Example of some code:

```
//mylib.h

  int func1(int x);
  int func2(int x);
  int func3();
```

in func3.c:

```
int func3()
{
int x1 = func1(int x);
int x2 = func2(int x);
return(x1 + x2);
}

  //func3 needs func1 and func2 which are defined in the same library
```

hope this makes any sense

Comment: "*#include "library.h" on the function inside library.h*". That is unclear. Please show code to illustrate an example of the exact scenario you are asking about. Please see how to post a [mre].

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how source and header files works, and what a library really is. A header file for a library is not the library itself, it's just a header file like any other, which includes declarations of the functions and structures needed to use the library. It can, and typically is, included in the source files that make up the actual library.

Comment: go with different file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, and you should. It is common sense to include the header file containing the public API of some code in the source file(s) implementing that code. This way the compiler checks for you that the prototypes (and other stuff like declarations) match their counterparts in the implementation source.

For example, the header file "mylib.h" is:

```c
#if !defined(MY_LIB_H)
#define MY_LIB_H

int func1(int x);
int func2(int x);
int func3(int x1, int x2);

#endif
```

This header file contains the so-called header-guard. It helps against multiple definitions if the header file is include multipl times, for example if you include it in multiple other header files, which are included in some source file.

And its implementation "mylib.c":

```c
#include "mylib.h"

int func1(int x) {
    return x;
}

int func2(int x) {
    return -x;
}

int func3(int x1, int x2) {
    return func1(x1) * func2(x2);
}
```